# Keyboard Hides Bottom Sheet in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, textfield, bottom-sheet

Flutter version - 3.3.10

I've tried all the various recommendations on this site, but nothing is working for me.

I have a bottom sheet that contains a `TextField` & I need it to be visible when the keyboard appears.

Everything I have tried has the same results, the bottom sheet stays where it is & the keyboard covers it.

Here's the last thing I have tried:

```
 showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Padding(
          padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(25),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(25),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(height: 12),
                    Center(
                      child: Container(
                        width: 40,
                        height: 5,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                            color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Text('hello'),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    _buildTextFieldWidget(),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

Comment: Did you find the solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using the **flutter_screenutil** plugin, add the following code to your ScreenUtilInit wrapper in main.dart:

```
ScreenUtilInit(
        useInheritedMediaQuery: true,
        ....
```